# Accessing various HTML navigator properties through a webview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose

I'm tasked with implementing a 3DS payment verification flow “natively”. We will of course be redirecting users, showing specific HTML content, making various calls, etc. according to the service provider.
Their API for initializing the 3DS process requests information such as :

> BrowserIP  string The IP of the client. It can be IPv4 or IPv6.
>
> Navigator_language     string Language according to IETF BCP47. Get this
> value from navigator.language HTML property.
>
> Navigator_javaEnabled  string Get this value from
> navigator.javaEnabled HTML property.
>
> Navigator_jsEnabled    string 'true' if javascript is enabled in
> client's browser. 'false' otherwise.
>
> Screen_colorDepth  string Get this value from screen.colorDepth HTML
> property.
>
> Screen_height  string Get this value from screen.height HTML property.
>
> Screen_width   string Get this value from screen.width HTML property.
>
> TimezoneOffset     string Get this value by running 'new
> Date().getTimezoneOffset();' in the client's browser.
>
> UserAgent  string It must contain the HTTP user-agent header value.
>
> BrowserAccept  string It must contain the HTTP accept header value.

I know that I can probably get the user's IP, JS-enabled, screen dimensions & user-agent string from the web view's settings & the device's configuration properties, but how would I access all these other fields? I couldn't find a navigator object attached to the web view or its settings. Is there a native way for retrieving all these details?

Answer (score 2):

Alright after a lot of playing around I figured it out! First and foremost I created a normal WebView using the `AndroidView` composable:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun Payments3DSWebViewScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    accountId: String?,
    cardInfo: CardInfo,
    paymentsViewModel: PaymentsViewModel = get()
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var webView by remember { mutableStateOf<WebView?>(null) }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                WebView(context).apply {
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    addJavascriptInterface(PaymentsJSInterface(), "ANDROID")
                    webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
                        override fun onJsAlert(
                            view: WebView?,
                            url: String?,
                            message: String?,
                            result: JsResult?
                        ): Boolean {
                            return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result)
                        }
                    }
                    webView = this
                    webView?.loadUrl("javascript: ANDROID.getNavigatorInfo(navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage, navigator.javaEnabled());")
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White)
        )
    }
    BackHandler {
        if (webView != null) {
            if (webView!!.canGoBack()) {
                webView?.goBack()
            } else {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
        } else {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
    }
}
```

Within it, I used a `WebChromeClient` instance instead of a regular `WebViewClient` since I read that it makes such things easier with its provided methods (i.e. onJsAlert()). Next up, I enabled javascript through the web view settings and finally added a custom JS Interface that will do all of the extraction work.

Here's the PaymentsJSInterface class:

```
class PaymentsJSInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun getNavigatorInfo(lang: String, javaEnabled: Boolean) {
        Log.d("PAYMENTJS", "$lang | $javaEnabled")
    }
}
```

So the extraction is achieved by running a custom JS script inside the webview using the `loadUrl()` method and specifying that the URL is a JS script (hence the `javascript:` at the beginning). Once you do that, you can access the JavascriptInterface methods (that are annotated with @JavascriptInterface through the "ANDROID" (in my case) 'namespace'. Since the JS code is running within a webView, you now have access to various HTML attributes such as the `Navigator` one. With that, I could extract the necessary info by calling my JSInterface's method with the necessary parameters!